# Spring '21 broke custom flow screen component's sizing

Tags: visual-workflow, aura

When Spring '21 hit, we noticed all our custom flow screen components lost their sizing arrangement.
[image: flow screenshot]
The components were in a 2-column layout using slds size_1-of-2.  Some initial debugging showed that now the components are wrapped in an additional div with no size and style
[image: inspect screenshot]

The outer most div wasn't there pre-Spring '21, which was probably why the sizing from components now rendered no effect.  Anyone else noticed the same issue?

Comment: Does this KI answer your query (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q7SoQAI&title=fields-not-aligned-in-flow)

Comment: That seems to be a different issue (with standard components) and is scheduled to be *resolved by* Spring '21... ours seems to be caused by the release :)